# On an equality of $x \bmod 1$ (the non-diagonal case)

Tags: real-analysis

Let $x \bmod 1\in \Bbb R$ be fractional part of $x \in \Bbb R$.

For what pairs of $(x,y) \in \Bbb R^2$ with $x\neq y$ is $x^2 \bmod 1 = (y \bmod 1)^2$? The case of $x=y$ was answered in [On an equality of $x \bmod 1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/470491/on-an-equality-of-x-bmod-1).

What about for higher powers?

Comment: This question is kind of wierd. You can always choose $y=\sqrt{\{x^2\}}+a$, where $a$ is an integer.

Comment: You could write it as an answer