# $\{x^2\} = \{x\}^2$, how many solutions in interval $[1, 10]$

Tags: graphing-functions, integers, ceiling-and-floor-functions, fractional-part

> Find how many solutions there are in the interval $[1, 10]$ to the fractional part equation:
> $$\left\{x\right\}^2 = \left\{x^2\right\}$$
> Where $\{\cdot\}$ is the fractional part function, meaning that:
> $$\left\{a\right\} = a - \left\lfloor a \right\rfloor$$

###### Some research about the problem:

I graphed both functions on a Graphing Calculator:
[image: Graph with intersections over a small interval]

And the problem was looking like it had a tremendous amount of solutions!

###### Approach

The equation is equivalent to:
$$(x - \lfloor x\rfloor)^2 = (x^2 - \lfloor x^2\rfloor)$$

So:
$$x^2 - 2x\lfloor x\rfloor + \lfloor x\rfloor^2 = x^2 - \lfloor x^2\rfloor$$

Further investigations lead to:
$$2x\lfloor x \rfloor \in \mathbb{Z}$$

In which I hope I could find a clue for solving, using divisibility arguments, however no information appeared obvious to me from this.

(References: the graph was made using GeoGebra Graphing)

Comment: You will like [this post](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c7h2086177p15041840).

Comment: @TeresaLisbon I was about to make a similar observation: $(n+1)^2-n^2=2n+1$, hence in $[n,n+1[$, $\{x^2\}$ have to "return to the origin" $2n+1$ times. That leaves $2n$ roots, because the last intersection point would be at exactly $n+1$, which is out of the interval.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut Thankfully, you can use the resource and your observations to write an answer, so I'll look forward to that!

Comment: You missed the solution $x=1$.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/470498/42969.

Comment: You are close to the solution, but better consider $2\{x\}\lfloor x\rfloor\in\mathbb Z$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $x=i+f, 0\le f<1$ (integer plus fractional parts).

The equation turns to

$$\{(i+f)^2\}=f^2$$ which simplifies to
$$2if=n$$ for some $n$.

Hence the solutions come with all fractions $$f=\frac{n}{2i}$$ with $0\le n <2i$.

Now count the possible values of $n$ for $i\in[1,10]$.

Comment: If $0 \leq n < 2i$, than all the solutions $\frac{n}{2i}$ are under $1$, so they could not be counted in $[1, 10]$.

Comment: @MathStackExchange: see my update.

Comment: Great. Now it's working with the mention that for $i = 10$, to stay in the interval, $f$ should be $0$...

Comment: @MathStackExchange: of course, for $i=10$, $n=0$ is the only possible value.

Answer (score 2):

Wow it's have so many solutions...

$\left\{{x}^{\mathrm{2}} \right\}={x}^{\mathrm{2}} −\left[{x}^{\mathrm{2}} \right]=\left\{{x}\right\}^{\mathrm{2}}  \\ $
${x}^{\mathrm{2}} −\left\{{x}\right\}^{\mathrm{2}} =\left[\left(\left[{x}\right]+\left\{{x}\right\}\right)^{\mathrm{2}} \right] \\ $
$\left[{x}\right]\left(\left[{x}\right]+\mathrm{2}\left\{{x}\right\}\right)=\left[{x}\right]^{\mathrm{2}} +\left[\mathrm{2}\left[{x}\right]\left\{{x}\right\}\right] \\ $
$\mathrm{2}\left[{x}\right]\left\{{x}\right\}=\left[\mathrm{2}\left[{x}\right]\left\{{x}\right\}\right] \\ $
$\left(\mathrm{2}\left[{x}\right]\left\{{x}\right\}\right)\in{Z} \\ $
${x}\in\left\{\mathrm{1},\mathrm{1}\frac{\mathrm{1}}{\mathrm{2}},\mathrm{2},\mathrm{2}\frac{\mathrm{1}}{\mathrm{4}},\mathrm{2}\frac{\mathrm{2}}{\mathrm{4}},\mathrm{2}\frac{\mathrm{3}}{\mathrm{4}},\right. \\ $
$\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\mathrm{3},\mathrm{3}\frac{\mathrm{1}}{\mathrm{6}},\mathrm{3}\frac{\mathrm{2}}{\mathrm{6}},\mathrm{3}\frac{\mathrm{3}}{\mathrm{6}},\mathrm{3}\frac{\mathrm{4}}{\mathrm{6}},\mathrm{3}\frac{\mathrm{5}}{\mathrm{6}}, \\ $
$\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\mathrm{4},\mathrm{4}\frac{\mathrm{1}}{\mathrm{8}},\mathrm{4}\frac{\mathrm{2}}{\mathrm{8}},\mathrm{4}\frac{\mathrm{3}}{\mathrm{8}},\mathrm{4}\frac{\mathrm{4}}{\mathrm{8}},\mathrm{4}\frac{\mathrm{5}}{\mathrm{8}}, \\ $
$\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\mathrm{4}\frac{\mathrm{6}}{\mathrm{8}},\mathrm{4}\frac{\mathrm{7}}{\mathrm{8}},\mathrm{5},\mathrm{5}\frac{\mathrm{1}}{\mathrm{10}},\mathrm{5}\frac{\mathrm{2}}{\mathrm{10}},\mathrm{5}\frac{\mathrm{3}}{\mathrm{10}}, \\ $
$\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\mathrm{5}\frac{\mathrm{4}}{\mathrm{10}},\mathrm{5}\frac{\mathrm{5}}{\mathrm{10}},\mathrm{5}\frac{\mathrm{6}}{\mathrm{10}},\mathrm{5}\frac{\mathrm{7}}{\mathrm{10}},\mathrm{5}\frac{\mathrm{8}}{\mathrm{10}},\mathrm{5}\frac{\mathrm{9}}{\mathrm{10}}, \\ $
$\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\mathrm{6}\frac{\mathrm{1}}{\mathrm{12}},\mathrm{6}\frac{\mathrm{2}}{\mathrm{12}},\mathrm{6}\frac{\mathrm{3}}{\mathrm{12}},\mathrm{6}\frac{\mathrm{4}}{\mathrm{12}},\mathrm{6}\frac{\mathrm{5}}{\mathrm{12}},\mathrm{6}\frac{\mathrm{6}}{\mathrm{12}}, \\ $
$\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\mathrm{6}\frac{\mathrm{7}}{\mathrm{12}},\mathrm{6}\frac{\mathrm{8}}{\mathrm{12}},\mathrm{6}\frac{\mathrm{9}}{\mathrm{12}},\mathrm{6}\frac{\mathrm{10}}{\mathrm{12}},\mathrm{6}\frac{\mathrm{11}}{\mathrm{12}},\mathrm{7},\mathrm{7}\frac{\mathrm{1}}{\mathrm{14}} \\ $
$\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\mathrm{7}\frac{\mathrm{2}}{\mathrm{14}},\mathrm{7}\frac{\mathrm{3}}{\mathrm{14}},\mathrm{7}\frac{\mathrm{4}}{\mathrm{14}},\mathrm{7}\frac{\mathrm{5}}{\mathrm{14}},\mathrm{7}\frac{\mathrm{6}}{\mathrm{14}},\mathrm{7}\frac{\mathrm{7}}{\mathrm{14}}, \\ $
$\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\mathrm{7}\frac{\mathrm{8}}{\mathrm{14}},\mathrm{7}\frac{\mathrm{9}}{\mathrm{14}},\mathrm{7}\frac{\mathrm{10}}{\mathrm{14}},\mathrm{7}\frac{\mathrm{11}}{\mathrm{14}},\mathrm{7}\frac{\mathrm{12}}{\mathrm{14}},\mathrm{7}\frac{\mathrm{13}}{\mathrm{14}}, \\ $
$\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\mathrm{8},\mathrm{8}\frac{\mathrm{1}}{\mathrm{16}},\mathrm{8}\frac{\mathrm{2}}{\mathrm{16}},\mathrm{8}\frac{\mathrm{3}}{\mathrm{16}},\mathrm{8}\frac{\mathrm{4}}{\mathrm{16}},\mathrm{8}\frac{\mathrm{5}}{\mathrm{16}},\mathrm{8}\frac{\mathrm{6}}{\mathrm{16}}, \\ $
$\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\mathrm{8}\frac{\mathrm{7}}{\mathrm{16}},\mathrm{8}\frac{\mathrm{8}}{\mathrm{16}},\mathrm{8}\frac{\mathrm{9}}{\mathrm{16}},\mathrm{8}\frac{\mathrm{10}}{\mathrm{16}},\mathrm{8}\frac{\mathrm{11}}{\mathrm{16}},\mathrm{8}\frac{\mathrm{12}}{\mathrm{16}}, \\ $
$\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\mathrm{8}\frac{\mathrm{13}}{\mathrm{16}},\mathrm{8}\frac{\mathrm{14}}{\mathrm{16}},\mathrm{8}\frac{\mathrm{15}}{\mathrm{16}},\mathrm{9},\mathrm{9}\frac{\mathrm{1}}{\mathrm{18}},\mathrm{9}\frac{\mathrm{2}}{\mathrm{18}},\mathrm{9}\frac{\mathrm{3}}{\mathrm{18}}, \\ $
$\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\mathrm{9}\frac{\mathrm{4}}{\mathrm{18}},\mathrm{9}\frac{\mathrm{5}}{\mathrm{18}},\mathrm{9}\frac{\mathrm{6}}{\mathrm{18}},\mathrm{9}\frac{\mathrm{7}}{\mathrm{18}},\mathrm{9}\frac{\mathrm{8}}{\mathrm{18}},\mathrm{9}\frac{\mathrm{9}}{\mathrm{18}}, \\ $
$\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\mathrm{9}\frac{\mathrm{10}}{\mathrm{18}},\mathrm{9}\frac{\mathrm{11}}{\mathrm{18}},\mathrm{9}\frac{\mathrm{12}}{\mathrm{18}},\mathrm{9}\frac{\mathrm{13}}{\mathrm{18}},\mathrm{9}\frac{\mathrm{14}}{\mathrm{18}},\mathrm{9}\frac{\mathrm{14}}{\mathrm{18}}, \\ $
$\left.\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\mathrm{9}\frac{\mathrm{15}}{\mathrm{18}},\mathrm{9}\frac{\mathrm{16}}{\mathrm{18}},\mathrm{9}\frac{\mathrm{17}}{\mathrm{18}},  \mathrm{10}\right\} \\ $

Answer (score 1):

Short way.

Write $x=n+\frac{k}{n}$ where $n$ is integer, $0 \leq k < n$, $k$ not necessarily an integer. Then:

$$\{x^2 \}=\{ (n+\frac{k}{n})^2 \}=\{ n^2+2k+(\frac{k}{n})^2 \}=\{2k+(\frac{k}{n})^2 \}$$

аnd

$$\{x \}^2=\{ n+\frac{k}{n} \}^2=\{ \frac{k}{n} \}^2$$

That means that we need to have

$$\{2k+(\frac{k}{n})^2 \}=\{ \frac{k}{n} \}^2$$

and this is possible only if $2k$ is an integer, since $k<n$. And this is giving $2n$ solution for each $n$ giving the total number of solutions:

$$1+\sum_{n=1}^{9}2n=9\cdot10+1=91$$

(Notice that $10$ participates only once.)